# MVC C# Redirect() to string url does not work

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

Im trying to retrieve a token from an url that must be redirected from my method. It works in a different method but doesn't work in this one.
Any help would be appreciated!

Controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Authorize(int clientId)
    {
        Session["client_Id"] = clientId;

        var client = GoogleAnalyticsHelper.CreateGoogleAnalyticsClient();

        string url = client.AuthorizeUrl();
        return Redirect(url);
    }
```

JavaScript:

```
function UpdateClient() {
var baseurl = "/GoogleAnalytics/";
var list = document.getElementById("clientId");
var clientId = list.options[list.selectedIndex].value;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    url: baseurl + "Authorize",
    data: { "clientId": clientId },
    success: function () {
        console.log("success!");
    },
    error: function (er) {
        console.log("an error occured: " + er);
    }
});
```

};

Button:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="UpdateClient()" name="button1" class="btn btn-info">Update client/ViewId</button>
```

Comment: JQuery's `ajax` function starts a separate (asynchronous) request. So when you send that separate request to your backend (`/GoogleAnalytics/Authorize`), it doesn't redirect the user's browser to your redirect url, but it redirects that separate request. What you can instead do is `return` the `url`, read out that value in your ajax request's `success` function, and then using `window.location.replace` to redirect the user's browser.

Comment: A good answer. To expand on it, I often return JSON with various fields such as whether the result was a success, the result value (url in your case), a message, and an error message so that you can cover the various outcomes which may occur. An example  from an action - return Json(new BookingResult() { IsSuccess = isSuccess, Message = datedMessage }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive found a solution and the problem was with Google Chrome. My solution in the success:

```
 success: function (url) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.assign(url);
        }, 0);
    },
```